# HTTP Failure , An error occured during URL invocation. ORA-12535: TNS:operation timed out

Tags: oracle-apex

There is a REST web service that I can successfully call from POSTMAN (just as a side note, I have to include a bearer token for it to work.)

I was doing research on how to call a rest web service from Oracle APEX, and found I can do that by creating a WEB SOURCE MODULE. This is the first screen where I add the URL of the endpoint
[image]

However when I click on NEXT, it takes a while before giving me this error:
[image]

Again, on POSTMAN I can successfully make the GET request, but I haven't figured out how to do it in Oracle APEX

Answer (score 0):

Note that for Oracle APEX *the database* is actually doing the HTTP request. A "TNS Timeout" error typically indicates that the database cannot reach the internet.

Did you specify a proxy server for your application (Shared Components > Application Definition Attributes > Proxy Server)?